# phone number Extracting from HTML Using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract a phone number from HTML using regex.
I am using this regex

```
\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}
```

for phone number `1234 546 567`. This regex successfully extracts the given phone number from HTML.

But a problem occurs when there is another number (which I *don't* want to extract) like this: `1234 567 89023`. Now from this number it is also extracting `1234 567 890` but I don't want it to extract anything from that number.

Then I changed the regex to

```
^\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3}$
```

but now it is not even extracting any valid numbers.

What should I do?
Edited:

```
string MatchAusPhoneNumber = @"\D(\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3})\D";
MatchCollection mathph2 = Regex.Matches(chk, MatchAusPhoneNumber);

foreach (Match matchio in mathph2)
{
    foreach (Capture capture in matchio.Captures)
    {
        if (my.ContainsKey(capture.Value) == false)
        {
            my.Add(capture.Value, capture.Value);
            mylist.Add(capture.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the vb.net tag?

Comment: \d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3, 5}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: I just reread your question and it sounds like you want to extract groups of 4-3-3 digits from HTML. If this is the case, try a regex like this:

```
\D(\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3})\D
```

`\D` will match everything except a digit. The `()` is to capture the actual phone number in the first capture group.

---

***Old Answer***: If you want for the last group of digits to be 3 to 5 characters, try this:

```
\d{4}\s\d{3}\s\d{3,5}
```

`\d{3,5}` means there can be `3` to `5` `\d`s.

Comment: OP doesn't want `1234 567 89023` to match!

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Yes he does. "Then I changed the regex to ... but now it is not extracting any number." That implies that he *wants* it to extract the number.

Comment: It sounds like @Nomi wants to match numbers inside text, in which case the  `^` and `$` aren't necessary (otherwise this won't match the first case).

Comment: i want only numbers (phonenumber)

Comment: @Nomi Oh, ok. I thought you wanted to match 5 digits also. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Nomi Why did you unaccept? Does it work?

Comment: @Doorknob  now out put changed to  0415 292 549<

Comment: @Nomi Did you make sure to use the first capture group instead of the entire match?

Comment: now it is  extracting this "<"

Comment: @Nomi Well, did you use the capture group? Could you show me your current code?

Comment: yes i edit my code check it plz

Comment: @Doorknob check it i mentioned my code above

Comment: @Nomi What language is that? Java, PHP, or ASP.NET? Why did you tag your question with *all* of these? Also, please don't leave two of the same comment.

Comment: I used C# i mentioned all languages because regular exprasion are same in all langueges.

Comment: @Nomi Actually regexes can have differences between languages. I tested it in Java and it worked. I can't help you because I don't know C#, so you might want to ask another question about why the capture group isn't being extracted.